# How to not parse a string with a number as a date?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to format a date string but for all other strings just return that input.
Now when the input is a string that contains any number e.g. "You are number 1", the string is parsed as a valid date "1 Jan 2001".

```
const value = new Date(input);
if (!(value instanceof Date && isFinite(value as unknown as number))) {
  return input;
}
// format date and return
```

How can I check if that string is really a string containing just a number or a date as string?
The input date string might always have the same pattern but ideally it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not that happy with the solution but it is working fine so far.

```
transform(input: string) {
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    return input;
  }
  
  if (input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length < 6) {
    return input;
  }
  // format the date ...
}
```

Test for that:

```
it('should ignore string and number values', () => {
  expect(pipe.transform('abc')).toBe('abc');
  expect(pipe.transform('This is not a date')).toBe('This is not a date');
  expect(pipe.transform('9999')).toBe('9999');
  expect(pipe.transform('000010')).toBe('000010');
  // will be parsed as a date
  expect(pipe.transform('Tue Sep 20 2022')).not.toBe('Tue Sep 20 2022');
});
```